# STM32 SWO traces disabled/settings overridden when using STM32_WPAN middleware

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

Using an STM32WB55 Bluetooth board, I followed [this guide](https://ralimtek.com/stm32_debugging/) to enable logging directly in STM32CubeIDE via the SWV ITM Data Console view, which works very well. Had to define my own _write function to override where printf sends its output.
However when I enable the STM32_WPAN middleware (which contains Bluetooth functionality that I absolutely want to take advantage of), it includes its own _write function, resulting in a duplicate declaration.

Is there any way to reconfigure the middleware to exclude its own debug config or tell it to use the same SWO based debugging that I'm currently using? Or do I have to manually overwrite the function?

Comment: `STM32_WPAN ` uses printf for debug ? it's not possible to disable it ? Usually you can define or undefine a compilation option to remove printf.

Comment: Logging in the project (official ST example) is done via function APP_DBG_MSG. 

STM32_WPAN defines: APP_DBG_MSG -> printf -> _write -> UART; 

I want: APP_DBG_MSG -> printf -> _write -> SWO

Comment: so why not modifying the `_write` function of WPAN ?

Comment: That's what I'm asking in the last sentence in my post - is there a better way than this :) Because I'd have to do that every time I reconfigure the project in MX view of STM32CubeIDE. During obligatory code generation after a config change, all manual changes in the file that declares the `_write` function in STM32_WPAN are reverted.